# How to generate files in a DevOps repo with Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a git based wiki as a repository containing .md files on Azure DevOps. I'd like to generate .pdf files out of the modified/added .md files after every push using the pipeline. I made the yml file which will call a bash script that checks for modified files and generates a pdf to the same folder. But I'm realizing this is a wrong approach since this file generation is a new push and will trigger the pipeline again. Also, the script probably needs an account to be able to do this.

Any suggestions how I can go about this?

The bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dependencies=("pandoc" "texlive-latex-base" "texlive-fonts-recommended" "texlive-extra-utils" "texlive-latex-extra")

updated=0

for dep in "${dependencies[@]}"
do
    dpkg -s $dep>/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    if [ $updated == 0 ]; then
        sudo apt-get update
        $updated=1
    fi
    sudo apt-get install $dep
    fi
done

commits=($(git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"%H"))

files=($(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM ${commits[1]}..${commits[0]} | grep .md))

for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    o_file=${file%.*}.pdf
    pandoc $file -o $o_file
    echo $file
done
```

Comment: File generation isn't a `git push`; only `git push` is a `git push`. Your `$updated=1` syntax is wrong but variable `updated` is never used (only set) so that's not too big a problem. You don't need to run `git log -n 2` at all: just refer to `HEAD` and `HEAD^` or `HEAD~`, or (better) use `git diff-tree` (you'll need to experiment with that on your own system first). What to do about Azure, I have no idea; the preceding is just commentary on Git and shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> file generation is a new push and will trigger the pipeline again:

You  can exclude the pdf file trigger.

```
trigger:
 branches:
    include:
    - main
 paths:
    exclude:
    - '**.pdf'
```

> the script probably needs an account to be able to do this:

Add PAT and  set git config when using git:

E.g.

```
  git clone https://{Your Azure PAT}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repos}
  git config --global user.email " user.email "
  git config --global user.name "name"
  cd XXX #CD to folder
  . . . 
  # do something that generate pdf
  . . .

  git push  origin main
```